# GitLab: remove/reset project history

Tags: git, gitlab

How to reset the project stream within GitLab after a rebase of the git repository?

The diffs of all previous commits are also still available within GitLab, although they are removed/rewritten in the git repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your rebase, you should try :

```
git push -f origin master
```

It should rewrite the history

Comment: It does not, the old tree will still linger - the object ids are reachable (if you have the hash) and you will see two trees in the graphs tab.

Comment: Any update on this @KrzysztofBociurko? How to make commits not available from the hashes or from the "Activities" menu in GitLab?

Comment: Haven't touched this issue since, @Cyrlop. As far as I remember, I fixed it with removing the project and re-adding it - fortunately this was a freshly migrated project and issue tracking was on another server.